# Unable to open CSS modal containing button in loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have created a simple modal in CSS using the code from javascript and HTML.
The triggered button is in a loop which is repeating many times. The first occurrence of triggered button works fine and modal shows up, but it doesn't show for rest of the content.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(){
  <!-- some html here-->
   <div class=" pull-left hs-book-now-button">
        <button id="myBtn">Book Now</button>     
    </div>
}
```

The modal html is:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>'modal content here'</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

And the javascript code is:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`, so if your loop is intending to create multiple buttons with unique click handlers attached, it won't work. The buttons have to have unique `id` values, then you'll have to figure out how to attach corresponding click handlers to each.

Comment: so can you suggest any alternate way? i can't figure it out

Comment: You can change the button to `<button id="myBtn">Book Now</button>` to `<button class="myBtn">Book Now</button>` and then `var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");` becomes `var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");` Do you know how to get the active element's content into the modal though?

Comment: i had tried this changing id to class. but its not even working for 1st occurrence of the button

Comment: @AsadUllah did you change your btn to be btn = getElementsByClassName("myBtn"), everything should now be stored into an array of elements with that class and you can access it using btn[0] btn[1] or whatever is needed